# Image montage - repeat

Tags: jquery, image, montage

Sorry for my english)

In general use plugin jquery - [AUTOMATIC IMAGE MONTAGE](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/30/automatic-image-montage/). Faced with a problem:

I have a few on the same page #am-container and using the plugin correctly displayed only in one but in the other does not work. Question. How to assign a function to all # s-container, not just one?

Code:

```
var $container  = $('#am-container'),
            $imgs       = $container.find('img').hide(),
            totalImgs   = $imgs.length,
            cnt         = 0;

        $imgs.each(function(i) {
            var $img    = $(this);
            $('<img/>').load(function() {
                ++cnt;
                if( cnt === totalImgs ) {
                    $imgs.show();
                    $container.montage({
                        fixedHeight : 90,
                        margin : 1,
                        fillLastRow : true
                    });
                    $container.montage++;
                }
            }).attr('src',$img.attr('src'));
        });
```

Comment: Try with a CSS class selector instead of an ID. IDs are supposed to be unique within 1 page, that could be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have duplicate id's. All ids need to be unique.
Because you have duplicate id's, JavaScript / jQuery only uses the first element with the id `#am-container`.

So you need to change your elements to have a classname.
The selector then would be `var $container  = $('.am-container')` instead of `var $container  = $('#am-container')`

Comment: The concept is simple!)
Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. Would you mind accepting this answer if it helped you out. Thanks.

Comment: Oh...Sorry)
Forgot :)